# Ubuntu 23.04 is quite laggy, please help

Tags: 23.04

So I've just installed the new Ubuntu version and I'm quite disappointed. I'm new to the whole tech industry trying to learn how to code and more so I installed Ubuntu to make use of it on a daily basis.
However I regret installing the new version as Terminal is super laggy and when I try to play videos they are incredibly laggy as well.

My computer is a Lenovo Ideapad gaming PC with 24gddr5Ram AMD Ryzen 5 6600 with over 1tb of ssd and RTX 3050. It should be able to run smoothly.

Could you help with clear instructions on what I should do as a beginner Ubuntu user, I want to become an expert but right now I don't really understand much, I have a bit of knowledge about ubuntu because when I was 15 I used a 2014 version of Ubuntu (it runned similiar but my hardware was trash)

I would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: I’m sorry you feel disappointed with Ubuntu. What you are experiencing is not typical. Rest assured with the specifications you have it should fly so something is wrong. You haven’t given us much to go on. Try opening the terminal and use the command `
journalctl -p 3 -b` Then add the output to your question as code. That may reveal something to work on.

Comment: Did you install the NVIDIA drivers? Go to “Software & Updates” In the "Software & Updates" window, go to the "Additional Drivers" tab. It should detect your graphics card and recommend a driver.